# Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Highcharts.chart is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, highcharts

I'm getting this error in my code:

```
TypeError: Highcharts.chart is not a function
    at Chart (file:///C:/Users/Mon%20PC/Desktop/Le%20bot/highcharts/index.js:7:24)
    at file:///C:/Users/Mon%20PC/Desktop/Le%20bot/highcharts/index.js:19:13
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
```

Full error: https://hastebin.com/share/ozijerocem.perl

Full code:

```js
import Highcharts from 'highcharts/highcharts.src.js';

// Load the exporting module.
import 'highcharts/modules/exporting.src.js';

export default function Chart() {
  const c = Highcharts.chart({
    title: {
      text: 'My custom title'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'My custom subtitle'
    }
  });

  return c.getSVG();
}

console.log(Chart());
```

If I use `highcharts/es-modules/masters/highcharts.src.js` and `highcharts/es-modules/masters/modules/exporting.src.js`, I get: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasOwnProperty')`

And if I use `highcharts/es5/highcharts.src.js` and `highcharts/es5/modules/exporting.src.js`, I get the same error:
`TypeError: Highcharts.chart is not a function`

**Node.js version**: 18.16.0

**I don't use Typescript, only Javascript**

**Highcharts version**: 11.1.0

Working on web, but not in my project...
https://pdkxxv-1234.csb.app/

Sandbox with node.js, same error happening (tested with `renderTo` and `callback` in addition of `options`): https://replit.com/@PauLem79/stackoverflowerrorhighcharts

**I use highcharts to send a chart in my discord server, I don't use it on web !**

Tried on Node.js v18, v16 and v12: same error

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the **API** (https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#Chart), the `Highcharts.chart` function takes three arguments:

- `renderTo` - the DOM element to render to, or its id
- `options` - the chart options
- `callback` - an optional function that runs after the chart was created

In your case, it's missing the `renderTo` argument so Highcharts does not have any container that it could render the chart to.

I've reproduced this problem here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cbfuhkj1/

If you open up the console you'll notice that Highcharts throws an error (error #13 - https://assets.highcharts.com/errors/13/).

I think that's the main reason why it does not work.

**If you add the `renderTo` argument, everything seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mtr67aef/**

If that does not solve your problem, please try to reproduce this error in an online code editor like JSFiddle or CodeSandbox so I could take a look again and propose another solution.

**Another reason:**

You're not importing the Highcharts modules correctly.

To import Highcharts we use: `import Highcharts from 'highcharts'` and to import a module and use we do:

```
import ExportingModule from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
ExportingModule(Highcharts);
```

Comment: I tried with `renderTo`, `callback`, and both (with `options`) but same error for all of them...
Here is the sandbox: https://replit.com/@PauLem79/stackoverflowerrorhighcharts

Comment: I've had some problems in replit, so I've created a demo in the CodeSandbox. The reason for this error might be the incorrect way of importing the Highcharts modules. Here's the correct way: https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-js-with-leaflet-forked-8cczlq

Comment: I get this error... `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasOwnProperty')
    at e (C:\Users\Mon PC\Desktop\Le bot\highcharts\node_modules\highcharts\modules\exporting.js:10:326)
    at C:\Users\Mon PC\Desktop\Le bot\highcharts\node_modules\highcharts\modules\exporting.js:11:4
    at file:///C:/Users/Mon%20PC/Desktop/Le%20bot/highcharts/index.js:5:1
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)`